# what can I use to display paragraph texts in kivy or kivymd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

A paragraph

[image]

Please what widget can I use to achieve or display a text like this in kivy or kivymd?

Comment: Use a Label widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Label and set the multiline parameter to True. It will automatically start a new line if the text is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  Scrollview, it has a lot of options for long texts
edit: This just to create a zone where you can put your Label (with multiline) and put a big amount of text to make it scrollable.